# How to change this code to work with an array of 100 objects?

Tags: c++

So, i'm practicing for the first time with array of objects and i'm currently trying to change a code that has 6 objects to work with an array of 100 objects. However, changing the functions to an array of 100 has been giving me problems(not storing the objects correctly). Since this is a new topic to me, maybe i'm doing something wrong that I haven't noticed. The code works perfect with 6 objects
This is the original function

```
 void input (Circle & C1, Circle & C2, Circle & C3, Circle & C4, Circle & 
 C5,
Circle & C6, int &count){
ifstream file;
file.open ("circles.txt");
int count_ = 0;
double diameter_, area_, perimeter_, radius_, centerx_, centery_;

cout << "The data in the file has been saved. " << endl;

while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0){
count++;
C1.setRadius (radius_);
C1.setCenterx (centerx_);
C1.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0)
{
count++;
C2.setRadius (radius_);
C2.setCenterx (centerx_);
C2.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0)
{
count++;
C3.setRadius (radius_);
C3.setCenterx (centerx_);
C3.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0)
{
count++;
C4.setRadius (radius_);
C4.setCenterx (centerx_);
C4.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0)
{
count++;
C5.setRadius (radius_);
C5.setCenterx (centerx_);
C5.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_)
{
if (radius_ > 0)
{
count++;
C6.setRadius (radius_);
C6.setCenterx (centerx_);
C6.setCentery (centery_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
};
};
```

This is what I tried to do

```
void input(Circle circle[], int &count) {
ifstream file;
file.open("circles.txt");
int count_ = 0;
double diameter_, area_, perimeter_, radius_, centerx_, centery_;
cout << "Saved. " << endl;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
while (file >> radius_ >> centerx_ >> centery_) {
if (radio_ > 0) {
count ++;
circle[i].setRadius(radius_);
circle[i].setCenterx(centerx_);
circle[i].setCentery(centroy_);
count_++;
break;
};
count_++;
cout << "Circle # " << count_ << " has invalid input. " << endl;
}
}
};
```

Same problem with this function(original code)

```
do
    {
      if (count == 0)
    {
      op_ = C1.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 1)
    {
      op_ = C2.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 2)
    {
      op_ = C3.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 3)
    {
      op_ = C4.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 4)
    {
      op_ = C5.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 5)
    {
      op_ = C6.newC (count);
    }
      else if (count == 6)
    {
      cout << "Full memory. " << endl;
      op_ = 'N';
    };
    }
  while (op_ == 'Y' && op_ == 'y' && count < 3);
  cout << endl;
```

(How I tried to change it)

```
   for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
            do {
                if (count == i) {
                    op_ = circle[i].newC(count);
                } else if (count == 100) {
                    cout << "No space left. " << endl;
                    op_ = 'N';
                };
            } while (op_ == 'Y' && op_ == 'y' && count < 100);
            cout << endl;
        }
```

Comment: _been giving me problems_ What sort of problems?  [Edit] your question to include details on what the problems are.

Comment: For example, when I changed that last function to an array of objects it shows as if 0 circles were saved, which means it didn't stored any objects, same goes for the first code. Basically it's not storing them correctly.

Comment: To be honest, you should have used arrays when you had 6 objects.  The code duplication for 6 objects is too much.  Also you shouldn't be hardcoding 100.  What if it's 8 objects, or 54 objects?  How do you keep track of the true number of objects?   Maybe that's why you're having issues -- the original code of 6 objects knew it was *only* 6 objects, while your new code has no idea the number of objects.

Comment: Use `std::vector`, not arrays.

Comment: The code you posted says `if ( radio_ > 0 )`. Are you sure this is correct? Shouldn't it be `radius_ > 0`?